# Pass a command line argument and use it in a command when using getline in awk

Tags: bash, awk, command-line-arguments, getline, argument-passing

I have a bash script which takes in 3 command line arguments. In the same bash script, I've also got an awk command where I am using this type of getline `command | getline var`.

I want to be able to pass in the second command line argument into the command. How can I go about this?

Comment: Use awk's `-v` option to define an awk variable with the value of a shell variable.

Comment: Glenn, you should post that as answer with an example...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want a construct somewhat like:

```
awk -v COMMAND="${2}" '{ system(COMMAND) | getline var }' -
```

As no detail is provided in the question, and since context for the "command | getline var" command is not provided in the question, this is a silly awk script that does nothing useful.  It is meant only to show how to pass variables into an awk script from within a BASH context.